# How to convert a for loop into a nested while loop w/ a working if statement in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm struggling at the moment in finding a way to convert my `for` loops to a good working set of `while` loops with a working `if statement` to create a multiplication table that looks like this:

[image: Click here for Multiplication table image]

Any suggestions or tips? I am using python 3.6.

This is what I have for the `for` loop to create the Multiplication table referenced above, how can I convert this to a working `nested while loop`:

```
print('x', end='\t')
for row in range (1,13):
    print(row, end='\t')
for row in range (1,13):
    print('')
    print()
    print()
    print(row, end='\t')
    for col in range(1,13):
        print(row*col, end='\t')
```

Comment: What is the purpose of converting this to `while` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your purpose but can do something like below

```
print('x', end='\t')
row = 1
while (row < 13):
    print(row, end='\t')
    row += 1
row = 1    
while (row < 13):
    print('')
    print()
    print()
    print(row, end='\t')
    col = 1
    while( col < 13):
        print(row*col, end='\t')
        col += 1
    row += 1
```

Comment: it's an assignment. however, it is good practice for me to learn how to convert and see the difference from for to while loops. i tend to overthink a lot when coding when the answer is very simple. thank you

Comment: this is what answer you were expecting?

Comment: to an extent, yes. I asked for an if statement as well, but I can figure out how to input that. thank you again.